# Oracle SQL - future date/employers age problem

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a problem with age of employeers.

In one table I have e_date_of_birth, e_employee_number, e_employee_name, and
in a second table w_employee_since.

I have an inquiry that returns employees with valid contracts for a particular day (e.g. 2016/01/01) and shows the current age of the employee on that day. 
I need to add an inquiry that shows employees with valid contracts as of a specific date (e.g. 2016/01/01), and also their age of another date (e.g. 2017/01/01) in the same query results.

Comment: Welcome. Make it easy to assist you, provide sample table data and expected result as formatted text (not images). And take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Is "I have an inquiry" supposed to mean "I have a query"? Then please show that query.

Comment: Please explain your tables in more detail. What are their unique keys? The first sounds like an employee table with one row per employee and `e_employee_number` being unique. Why then is `w_employee_since` in another table? Can one employee have more than one row in that second table? How to interprete their rows then? Does that table also contain an employee number or how else are the two tables related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details about your tables, particularly wherever you have the contracts information, a generic query to find employee age on a given date would look something like this.

```
SELECT FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE '2017-01-01', e_date_of_birth)/12) AS age
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: That's great! Please flag it as the answer, if so.